# PHP: Remove all hyperlinks of specific domain from text

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

**2 things:**

1. Remove all hyperlinks that point to mydomain.com & retain all other hyperlinks that do not belong to this domain.
2. For all the other URLs that remain, grab the value between  tags and show it as ID.

**1. About 1st task:**

**I have this:**

```
$str = 'I have been searching <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> for all the valuable information. I have also tried <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> and I finally, ended up finding it at
<font size="1">My Site <a style="color:#0000ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" href="http://www.mydomain.com/go.php?offer=fine&amp;pid=10" target="_blank" >My Link</a></font>. So you can visit <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/go.php?offer=ok" target="_blank">My Link</a>';
```

**I want this:**

```
$str = 'I have been searching <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> for all the valuable information. I have also tried <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> and I finally, ended up finding it at . So you can visit ';
```

**What  I tried:**

I tried the following preg_replace but it removes all the links. I just want it to remove all links from mydomain.com and retain everything else as it is.

```
$pattern = "/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU";
$final_str = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $str);
```

**2. About 2nd task:**

**Finally, I want to end up with this:**

```
$str = 'I have been searching <a href="http://www.google.com" id="Google">Google</a> for all the valuable information. I have also tried <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="Yahoo">Yahoo</a> and I finally, ended up finding it at . So you can visit ';
```

Comment: Answer to both questions: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML using regex. You will (/ You are) fail(ing).

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick in 2 steps:

```
<?

$str = 'I have been searching <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> for all the valuable information. I have also tried <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> and I finally, ended up finding it at <font size="1">My Site <a style="color:#0000ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" href="http://www.mydomain.com/go.php?offer=fine&amp;pid=10" target="_blank" >My Link</a></font>. So you can visit <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/go.php?offer=ok" target="_blank">My Link</a>';

// removing the domain links
$pattern1 = '|<a [^>]*href="http://www.mydomain.com[^"]*"[^>]*>.*</a>|iU';
$str = preg_replace($pattern1, '', $str);

// adding IDs
$pattern2 = '|(<a [^>]+)>(.*)</a>|iU';
$str = preg_replace($pattern2, '$1 id="$2">$2</a>', $str);
```

Let me know if you also need to get rid of the `<font size="1">My Site </font>` part.